# Ractive.js flip boolean function

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I am new to Javascript (started today) and I am using the Ractive framework to make a web app to deliver an analytics product. I am trying to make a function that flips a boolean value in the .on function. I have something like this but it isn't working. Can someone help me about how to think about this problem?

```
ractive.on('flipBool', function ( ) {
  ractive.set( 'theData.*.Visible', !'theData.*.Visible' );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from ofrommel's answer, I thought I'd quickly explain what's going on in the initial code snippet, as it might be helpful in future.

When you call `ractive.set('theData.*.Visible', !'theData.*.Visible')`, you're setting everything that matches `theData.*.Visible` to a single value, which is `!'theData.*.Visible` - and because the `!` operator simply negates whatever follows it, and a non-empty string is considered truthy, `!'theData.*.Visible' === false`. So it's the equivalent of doing this:

```
ractive.set( 'theData.*.Visible', false );
```

So instead of using the keypath in the second argument, you have to actually *get* the value of the keypath:

```
// this...
ractive.toggle( 'foo' );

// ...is equivalent to this:
ractive.set( 'foo', !ractive.get( 'foo' ) );
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't actually work with keypaths that contain the `*` character:

```
// this...
ractive.toggle( 'theData.*.Visible' );

// ...is equivalent to this...
ractive.set( 'theData.*.Visible', !ractive.get( 'theData.*.Visible' ) );

// ...which is equivalent to this:
 ractive.set( 'theData.*.Visible', true );
```

Because `ractive.get('theData.*.Visible')` is always `undefined`, that means that toggling the value will always set all matching keypaths to `true`, which isn't what you want. (I've [just opened an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1604) to address this.)

So the best way to achieve what you want, at present, is to iterate through the array and update everything manually, like so:

```js
ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    people: [
      { name: 'Alice', visible: false },
      { name: 'Bob', visible: true },
      { name: 'Caroline', visible: true },
      { name: 'Dave', visible: false },
      { name: 'Eric', visible: false }
    ]
  },
  flipBool: function () {
    var changes = {};
    this.get( 'people' ).forEach( function ( person, i ) {
      changes[ 'people.' + i + '.visible' ] = !person.visible;
    });
    this.set( changes );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>

<main></main>

<script id='template' type='text/html'>
  <button on-click='flipBool()'>flip</button>
  
  {{#each people}}
    {{#if visible}}
      <p>{{name}} is visible</p>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Great answer. This helps me so much. You're the best.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the Ractive `toggle()` function?

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Just wasted an hour of my life.